# How to configure Avro MapReduce job to output results into a single file?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, avro

I have a three nodes cluster and when the Avro job completes, it creates three output files (split files), however, I would like to output only one file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set mapred.reduce.tasks=1, but this might increase the execution time.

You could also use hadoop -getmerge command to get a single file after the job is over.

Comment: Thanks Venkat, It's in fact time consuming process but at least it resolves my issue for now. many thanks :-)